# UITableview large number of images

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, lazy-loading

I understand that this question has been asked a few times on stackoverflow. 
However, I am looking for something more advanced here.

My clients app is basically an e-commerce app that has about 40-50 sales at a time. And within a given sale, there are between 100-300 products.

Given the number of images, each approximately 150x200pi in size, I need to get these to load faster.

I am already using SDWebImage library for fetching images. ( I have even tried AfNetworking and Apple's LazyLoadImages). 
I am pre-fetching some images when possible. But the client still needs it to be faster. I have seen some apps like Amazon's My Habit ios app load images almost seamlessly. I am still not close to that.

Given the sheer number of images it is hard to predict which ones to prefetch, it is not possible to predict what the user might choose to see.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really implement your own cache. You need a two layer cache: one for full-size images and one for thumb images.

For the full-size images, your cache shall hold N*C + 2*C images at max, where N is the number of visible rows and C is the number of visible columns - assuming one can scroll only rows.

For a table view with 1 column, let the number of visible rows be 10. Then, the maximum number of full-size images becomes 12.

For a table view with 1 column and 10 visible rows, your cache must hold the images for rows in range [LB-1 .. UB+1], where LB is the lower bound index and UB is the current upper bound index of the *visible* rows.

(Note: if the images are small, you may widen the range carefully!)

You need to evict and load the images as the user scrolls. Switching the current visible range of row-indices happens when half a row hight has been scrolled.

When a load of an image is required, this image will not be visible yet: assuming the user scrolls in one direction, it's still half a row hight away from becoming visible. You need to utilize this short time frame to properly prepare the image so that it can be rendered quickly (actually create the bitmap).

You also need a second image cache for the thumbs. This is equally designed, it just has a larger range for load ahead, say [LB-10 .. UB+10], or even much more.

Your methods shall be asynchronous and employ the lazy initialization pattern:

When you have to draw an image, check whether the full-size is already available. If yes, draw it, otherwise load it asynchronously and check if the thumb image is already available, if yes draw it, otherwise load it asynchronously and draw a static placeholder. Your loading methods shall run asynchronous!

When a load finished, check if the cell is visible and update the image. The thumb image may override the placeholder image, and the full-size image may override both. Otherwise, not.

As an optimization, disable loading of the full-sized images when the user scrolls "fast". You need to empirically figure out what "fast" is.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solutions  is to cache your image once you retrieve them.

Here is a nice example how to do that

http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu/~wayne/yellowjacket/YellowJacket.zip

Comment: Both SDWebImage and AFNetworking are already doing caching internally.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common in this cases that the backend should provide two images, one fairly small and one with full resolution. When the user is scrolling you fetch the small image with cache as you're already doing, but if for example, the UITableViewCell remains visible for more than two seconds, you proceed to fetch the high-resolution image.

Comment: This sounds like it could work. But keeping track of how long each image as been visible seems too expensive, no? Or am i misunderstanding something?